# Updating document title without hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Is it required to use a hook for updating `document.title`? Is there any advantage to using `useEffect` vs. just setting the title directly as below?

(This snippet also echoes the title to the console, since you can't see the document title in Stack Snippets, but in my real code I'm just updating the title.)

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
  console.log(document.title);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

(Note: This is the [`useEffect` example](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) without the `useEffect` call.)

Comment: Docs does say *"Unlike componentDidMount or componentDidUpdate, effects scheduled with useEffect don’t block the browser from updating the screen."*, however adding a big loop in `useEffect` still freezes browser

Comment: @Rajesh - Of course, because there's only one main UI thread on browsers. But that happens *after* the DOM has been updated, rather than before, because the effect callback is called after the DOM has been updated.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i was hoping they would have added web worker or something to handle that based on the message. Not sure what they really meant by *don't block the browser*

Comment: @Rajesh - I believe they mean don't block the browser while rendering the components, but... I wish I had a deeper understanding of hooks so I could answer this. I mean, I know component functions should be pure, putting all side-effects in `useEffect`, but that just begs the question: *Why* should they be pure? I think the answer relates to not blocking the render and the fact React is aware of the *order* of hook calls in the component and that that can matter (and more obvious things, like you can tell react not to do the effect unless `count` changes, and optionally do cleanup), but...

Comment: @ Nat - [This article](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) is probably helpful. As I mention above, I wish I could post a useful answer.

Answer (score 3):

It may cause inconsistency in the future.

After concurrent mode, render may be abandoned when high priority task comes before react lifecycle.

Then at that moment document.title is not equal to the value in dom.

In your case, maybe title is `You clicked 2 times` but dom `You clicked 1 times`.

It is not what react is doing now(react@16). But it will happen.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it required to use a hook for updating document.title?

No, because setting the title twice does not cause any harm.

> Is there any advantage to using useEffect vs. just setting the title directly as below?

If you would `useEffect` correctly, it would only update the title if the count actually changed. As there is only one state in your component however, it will only rerender if the count updated, thus it makes no difference in this case.

If you scroll down, you'll see that the tutorial you mentioned changes it to this at the end (which will do what I just described):

```
 useEffect(() => {
  document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
 }, [count]);
```

Comment: Consider SSR where `document` is not even present. `useEffect` will make a clear difference there.

Comment: @ivan relying on syntactically wrong code to not execute is generally a bad idea.

Comment: What exactly is "syntactically wrong"? My comment is related to your first claim: "No, because setting the title twice does not cause any harm".